# How to change buttons when UpSlidePanel comes up in android

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, slideup, android-sliding

I am trying to make an app. I have implements the following sliding up panel 
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

I am not able to figure out that how should I change the buttons when the panel is slided up.

For example, look the images attached

**When the sliding panel is in the bottom, the pause, next and previous buttons are shown.**

[image]

**When I drag the panel up , the buttons are changed to some kind of toolbar with the "Now playing" text and other buttons**

[image]

How can I implement this in my app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a listener and callback methods with this library and you can manipulate the `panel` using an anonymous inner class that implements the interface methods, basic example :

```
        SlidingUpPaneLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
        mSlidingUpPaneLayout.setPanelSlideListener(new SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelSlideListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelCollapsed(View panel) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelExpanded(View panel) {

                panel.findViewById(R.id.myPanel)
                        .setBackgroundColor("whatever_resource_color");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelAnchored(View panel) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelHidden(View panel) {
            }
        });
```

In your case you could use a `FrameLayout` with 2 views, toggling the visibility to each view when the panel is closed or expanded, or something similar.